# Android Bluetooth Low Energy documentation for broadcast update function only receive one input parameter

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating an Android app for scanning, pairing, and reading data from a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) device.

Now, I'm implementing [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-ble-data#java) for reading data from a BLE device.

But as you can see in the screenshot below, there is something wrong with the documentation.

The `broadcastUpdate()` function in the right section of the image is declared with two inputs parameters.

But the `broadcastUpdate()` functions in the left section of the image are called with only one input parameter.

So my question is **what is the second input parameter** for those `broadcastUpdate()` functions that are declared by only using one input parameter?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am not familiar with BLE on Android, but if you fully read [the section about reading the characteristics](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-ble-data#read), seems like the `BluetoothGattCallback` class has a [`onCharacteristicRead`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int)) method, which will give you the desired second parameter.

Comment: You're right @gthanop.

But there the error is in ```onConnectionStateChange()``` function and there is no ```BluetoothGattCharacteristic``` object passed to the function

Comment: The implementation of `broadcastUpdate` with a single argument is in [the *Broadcast updates* section of the previous page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-gatt-server#broadcast-updates). The implementation of `broadcastUpdate` with 2 arguments is in the section about reading the characteristics. Calling the 2-arg version is inside the implementation of your `BluetoothGattCallback`, specifically in the `onCharacteristicRead` method which gives you the second parameter. `onConnectionStateChange` simply calls the 1-arg version.